# How to retrieve the co-ordinates for which I am getting the minimum difference value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates, distance, difference

I have a matrix X(20 by 2). I have fixed 6 beacon nodes and 1 sensor node. I have used these formulas to get the average value and the actual calculated distance-

```
%Euclidean distance from beacon nodes to known sensor node
d1 = pdist2(B1,S,'euclidean');

% Adding Gaussian Error and calculate avg
%1st beacon
for i=1:10
        d1 = d1 + erf(d1);
       d11(i)=d1;
end   
davg1 = mean(d11);

%distance from beacon nodes to generated sensor nodes

D1 = pdist2(X, B1);
```

I have the least difference of distance value of some co-ordinates. Here, difference of distance means deviation from the average distance. I have used this formula to get all the differences of distances-

```
y = [abs(D1-davg1), abs(D2-davg2), abs(D3-davg3), abs(D4-davg4), abs(D5-davg5), abs(D6-davg6)];
```

Here, davg1,...davg6 is the average distances(with error) from 6 beacon nodes to the sensor node. D1,....D6 is the euclidean distances from X to all 6 beacon nodes. 
I have used the function in my code as this-

```
Y(m,:) = Func(X(m,:));
```

In Y, I am getting all the differences, and after sorting them, I have got the least difference of distance. Now, I want to get the co-ordinates for which I am getting the least difference value. How can I retrieve the co-ordinates of X? Here I am expecting 6 different co-ordinates for the 6 beacon nodes. How can I do that? Please help because I cannot explain this problem to google...

Comment: Did you try to use multiple return values for function Func? like  `function[y, coor] = Func(x)`

Comment: I am assuming that `Func` is sorting the values. Is that a user-defined function? Can you put a link to that `Func`tions documentation?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, however, assuming that your variable `D` has the same order as `X` (i hope you dont shuffle inside your function) you should just use `[B,I] = sort(___)` (read [sort](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)), from which you can infer the order. Your question is difficult to understand, it is unclear what you tried and additionally it has no example of the desired input/output characteristics, for the future please read [ask].